# How to scrape SVG element from a website using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, svg, beautifulsoup

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import random

id_url = "https://codeforces.com/profile/akash77"
id_headers = {
    "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0(Windows NT 6.1Win64x64) AppleWebKit / 537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 87.0 .4280 .141 Safari / 537.36 '}
id_page = requests.get(id_url, headers=id_headers)
id_soup = BeautifulSoup(id_page.content, 'html.parser')

id_soup = id_soup.find('svg')
print(id_soup)
```

I'm getting `None` as the output for this.

If I parse the `<div>` element in which this `<svg>` tag is contained, the contents of the `<div>` element are not getting printed. The `find()` works for all HTML tags except the SVG tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webpage is rendered dynamically with Javascript, so you will need [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html) to get the rendered page.

First, install the libraries

```
pip install selenium
pip install webdriver-manager
```

Then, you can use it to access the full page

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

s=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://codeforces.com/profile/akash77')
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="userActivityGraph"]')
```

Elements is a selenium WebElement, so we will need to get HTML out of it.

```
svg = [WebElement.get_attribute('innerHTML') for WebElement in elements]
```

This gives you svg and all  elements inside it.

[image]

Sometimes, you need to run a browser in headless mode (without opening a chrome UI), for that you can pass a 'headless' option to the driver.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('headless')

# then pass options to the driver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
```

Comment: Just curious, what's the use of `driver.maximize_window()`?

Comment: I just like to use it to see how the rendered page looks like, then see the selectors or click the elements I'm looking for. Completely optional here thought.

Comment: This code will make a browser window appear? I assumed it would work headless.

Comment: Yeah, it will open a new chrome webpage with the rendered content.

Comment: @Green绿色 thinking about it, you're correct and often for repetitive tasks we need a headless mode, so I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

svg tag is not included in the source code, it is rendered by Javascript.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the data it is there in the html, this isn't pretty but it works and much quicker and easier than browser automation:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://codeforces.com/profile/akash77'

resp = requests.get(url)

start = "$('#userActivityGraph').empty().calendar_yearview_blocks("
end = "start_monday: false"

s = resp.text
svg_data = s[s.find(start)+len(start):s.rfind(end)].strip()[:-1].replace('items','"items"').replace('data','"data"').replace('\n','').replace('\t','').replace(' ','') #get the token out the html
broken = svg_data+'}'

json_data = json.loads(broken)
print(json_data)
```